# Time series regression - having problems trying to predict with KRR and gaussian process regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, gaussian-process

I need to predict what the output will be depending on the time. I want to make it so i can train my model on the first 20% of the data, and then make a model, that will follow the behavior, and predict the remaining 80%.
The data i am working on looks as follows:
[My data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gigE3.png)

But when i try to make regressions to do this, i either get something way off target (or something quite close, but then it is linear), which is not accepted.

I maybe think my problem is the choice of my kernel, or the way i am making the regressions. Right now i am making the with the sklearn package as follows:

```
gpr=GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=1.15**2*RBF(length_scale=41.4) + WhiteKernel(noise_level=1.32e-4),
  n_restarts_optimizer=10, 
  optimizer='fmin_l_bfgs_b',
  normalize_y=True,
  alpha=0.051)

gpr.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_gpr, y_std = gpr.predict(X_test, return_std=True)
```

But after a few predictions, the predictions just become the same steady value, instead of having the curve as in the data. Also, the standard variations for the prediction becomes very large.
[The GPR prediction on the real data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPCNf.png)

When doing the Kernel Ridge Regression in python, i can't seem to get the curve to follow the data aswell. Either it drops to 0 in a few predictions, or it has to be a linear prediction.
[The KRR model, but linear instead - which is not good enough](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcmDz.png)

The KRR model is made as follows (and i know the kernel=polynomial with a degree of 1, but i cant seem to figure out/find an appropiate kernel that will follow my data):

```
#The kernel ridge regression
krr = KernelRidge(alpha=0.051,kernel='polynomial',degree=1)
# krr = KernelRidge(alpha=0.051,kernel=RBF(0.5))
krr.fit(X_train,y_train)
list_y_pred=krr.predict(X_test)
```

So if possible, i would like to get some inputs, of how it should be done instead, or if a different approach to the problem would be better. But i am really hoping i can get the KRR to fit the data, and the gaussian process regression aswell.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing absolutely wrong with your code. I believe your parameters are wrong and the guess is not the best because of it.

My sugestion would be to use [grid search and pipelines](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html) to estimate the best parameters.

An example of how it would work would be

```py
param_grid = [
  {'alpha': [1, 10, 100, 1000], 'kernel': ['linear']}, ## test linear kernel with varying alpha
  {'alpha': [1, 10, 100, 1000], 'gamma': [0.001, 0.0001], 'kernel': ['rbf']}, # test rbf kernel while varying gamma and alpha
 ] 
   ## you can have as many dictionaries as you want inside this list, or just 1. Keep in 
   ## mind this takes O(n^n)*time_per_fit where n is the number of arguments you try to test, so 
   ## it can take a long time

estimator = KernelRidge()
clf = clf = GridSearchCV(estimator, param_grid)
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
list_y_pred=clf.predict(X_test)
```

For a more comprehensive tutorial try taking a look at the oficial docs [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html) and [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV), or even [here for a faster, but less thorough search](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV).

Keep in mind my parameters are way off, I just copied the example from the docs